# Moment js issue in getting relative time - fromNow()

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am trying to display relative time using moment.js fromNow(). But the values are rounded and displaying higher values instead of completed time. For instance,

```
moment().subtract('s',110).fromNow() //is giving '2 minutes ago' but I want this to be '1 minute ago'

moment().subtract('m',110).fromNow() //is giving '2 hours ago' but I want this to be '1 hour ago'

moment().subtract('h',44).fromNow() //is giving '2 days ago' but I want this to be '1 day ago'
```

How can we display only the completed time (minutes/hours/days) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging the moment.js documentation found the solution for my issue,

```
// Round relative time evaluation down
moment.relativeTimeRounding(Math.floor);

moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 60);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 24);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d', 31);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('M', 12);
```

relativeTimeRounding - sets the rounding function.
relativeTimeThreshold - sets the cutoff/threshold value for seconds,minutues,hours,etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use moment().diff(),you can get the difference in milliseconds, the doc: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

You can make your function to return the result you want.

Sorry for my english is pool, but I wish to help you.

Comment: Thank you. But diff will not give the result in 'x time ago' format

Comment: But you can write a function like that: